# spring-cloud-zookeeper-dependencies 1.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is missing

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud, spring-io

Since several days i got the maven error that the spring-cloud-zookeeper-dependencies/1.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is missing in https://repo.spring.io/snapshot

Can anybody please check this? Many Thanks, Best regards

Comment: Why are you using an old snapshot version?

Comment: New 1.0.4 snapshots are there now BTW